# Are custom DNS names and TLS bindings peristed during Azure ARM Template re-deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

**The Situation:**

We have deployed multiple identical App Service instances for a client using a custom ARM template. These services are hosted on the client's own Azure Account. 
After our deployment, the client went and manually configured custom DNS names and TLS certs for all web facing instances. We don't have access to their private certs (nor do we want it):

[image]

Everything works, but...

**The Problem:** 
I'm worried that the TLS configurations will be flushed if/when we have to re-deploy our ARM template. Ordinarily I would customized and re-reploy all instances when the client wants to change some settings.
I need to make sure that their TLS configuration isn't lost in such a situation.

I have the ARM configuration for the DNS and TLS bindings (referencing the private cert thumbprint), perhaps incorporating these blocks into our ARM template is enough to persist the client's configuration?

```
 {
     "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
     "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
     "name": "[concat(parameters('site_name'), '/', parameters('site_name'), '.xxxxxx.com')]",
     "location": "West Europe",
     "dependsOn": [
         "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('site_name'))]"
     ],
     "properties": {
         "siteName": "site-name",
         "hostNameType": "Verified",
         "sslState": "SniEnabled",
         "thumbprint": "45DA3B...67"
     }
 }

 ...     

 "hostNameSslStates": [
 {
     "name": "[concat(parameters('site_name'), '.xxxxxx.com')]",
     "sslState": "SniEnabled",
     "thumbprint": "45DA3B...67",
     "hostType": "Standard"
 },
 ...
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to preserve and incorporate the customer's TLS settings even if don't have access to the private cert?
I couldn't find a definitive answer in the Azure ARM documentation.

**Clarification:**
I'm aware that there are cleaner ways to automate the DNS/TLS configuration through ARM, but right now I can't change the setup and need to work with what I've got.

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't do the SSL configuration via ARM, it is best to completely omit these parts from your ARM template. We have the same situation, and it works just fine. Make sure that ARM is executed in incremental mode, otherwise you will probably get issues.

- Don't deploy any `Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings` resources with your ARM template
- Remove `hostNameSslStates` from your `Microsoft.Web/sites` resource

You can test it with an ARM template as simple as [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-webapp-basic-windows):

```
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "kind": "app",
      "name": "[variables('webAppPortalName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]"
      ]
    }
```

Your SSL configuration will not be touched, so your bindings remain intact. This is a common ARM behavior. If you don't specify a certain part of the template, it will not be touched. If you specify an array however, it will replace the whole array. ARM does not merge in this case. This is why you should omit `hostNameSslStates`.